# How do you transfer ether from msg.sender to some address?

Tags: solidity

I need to transfer ether from msg.sender to an address in solidity.How should i do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make payable function in you contract, and check amount of ether that was transferred by user to your contract:

```
require(msg.value == 1 ether, 'Wrong ether value transferred');
```

next you can transfer corresponding amount to destination address:

```
address(_dst).send(1 ether);
```

or in one function:

```
address(_dst).send(msg.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you should use `call` instead of `transfer` or `send`. More on that here: https://consensys.net/diligence/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/